# Restrict multiple access to a webpage at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am building a website which requires users to purchase an access code to view a particular web page. I want to restrict the user from using one access code across multiple devices at the same time. One access code should be used on one device and one browser tab at a time. I have already tried to restrict this by storing a flag in database using ajax call when the access code is being used. It sets the flag to 1 when it is accessed and changes the flag to 0 when it detects the tab being closed using the javascript **onbeforeunload** and **onunload** functions. But these functions are not reliable as they do not trigger on multiple occasions and the flag remains 1 even after closing the tab. I can't seem to think of any other method to restrict this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event

Comment: @Teemu Thank you. But this is causing the same issues as the onbeforeunload and onunload functions is not reliable.

Comment: Use both, just create a flag to mark the task is executed.